# Making a serial in serial out adder

Tags: vhdl

I am confused about sequential logic with components (I am new). 
I have these components, but I get confused how to use them within a process. I need help understanding how sequential logic works with components, also I am unsure if my input/output vectors are correct. I'm having trouble with the inputs and outputs for the shift registers, like if x(0) <= sin is the right call.

I have to design this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwVdw.jpg)

This is my main file

````
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity sa_top is
  port( 
        x:      in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        y:      in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        clk:    in STD_LOGIC;
        rst:    in STD_LOGIC;
        s:      out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
       );
end sa_top;

architecture Behavioral of sa_top is

-- shift register
component sr is
    port( 
          sin:  in STD_LOGIC;
          sout: out STD_LOGIC;
          clk:  in STD_LOGIC;
          rst:  in STD_LOGIC
         );
end component sr;

-- d flip/flop
component dff is 
    port( 
           d:   in STD_LOGIC;
           q:   in STD_LOGIC;
           clk: in STD_LOGIC;
           rst: in STD_LOGIC
           );
end component dff;

-- full adder
component fa is
    port( 
            a:     in STD_LOGIC;
            b:     in STD_LOGIC;
            cin:   in STD_LOGIC;
            sum:   out STD_LOGIC;
            cout:  out STD_LOGIC
         );
end component fa;

signal xi, yi, si: std_logic;
signal xo, yo, so: std_logic;


signal s_temp: std_logic;
signal carry: std_logic;

begin
xi <= x(0);
yi <= y(0);


inp_x_instance:  sr port map(sin => xi, sout => xo, clk => clk, rst => rst);
inp_y_instance:  sr port map(sin => yi, sout => yo, clk => clk, rst => rst);

adder_instace:   fa port map(a => xo, b=> yo, cin => carry, sum => si, cout => carry);

op_s_instance:   sr port map(sin => si, sout => so, clk => clk, rst => rst);

--df_instance: dff port map(d => s_temp, q => s_temp, clk => clk, rst => rst);

    process(clk, s_temp) is
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            s <= (others=>'0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            s(0) <= so;
         end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;```
````

Comment: Based on the diagram, should `sin` for the `sr` component not be a `std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)` ?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, however I was using the language template for shift register ( the one vivado provides ) and based off that, I thought the input was std_logic.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm getting confused with the serial in part for the shift register (sr), should it take in a std_logic_vector as a argument, or std_logic? To me it makes sense to use std_logic_vector; however I am not sure if that is the right call.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is correct, the only thing that you maybe got confused about is the actual shifting itself, you need to shift it the bits by 1 to the left into the other bits. Which can look something like this:

```
s(7 downto 1) <= s(6 downto 0);
```

So the final piece of code should look like this: (note that I have removed s_temp from the sensitivity list of the process)

```
process(clk) is
begin
    if rst = '1' then
        s <= (others=>'0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        s(7 downto 1) <= s(6 downto 0);
        s(0) <= so;
     end if;
end process;
```